# Layers/Overlay Factory-reset issues

Tags: twrp, overlay

I resetted my tablet (The survivor, see profile for make and model) as per its quarterly cleanup I run to keep my old data stored on a lovely drive while it is all wiped in TWRP. The process is fairly automated, just a good shell program sitting on a Linux desktop. However, I returned after the clean to find the screen on, but black (The lights are on, but there is nobody home). I believe this is because of the Steel overlay I was using via Layers manager may have broken (Overlays are stored in /system/vendor/overlays) And I cant see the system UI. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Managed to, after a bit of fiddling, I removed the bugged files (found them in /vendor/overlay)  and it is a-ok!